# RSelenium Youtube channels Extraction not Working in Loop

Tags: r, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to apply a loop for my extraction code. I am a begginer doing web scraping and I have not been able to iterate the code to the 100 channels and made my extration info. Next I show you how I tried to iterate it but I still get only 1 record, I think the problem is that the code does not allow to return to the main screen and select a new one.

```
URL: https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/af
   
remDr$navigate("https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/af")

#This is an example from 2 channel, but here have to go the 100 channels
channels <- c("/html/body/div[12]/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/a","/html/body/div[12]/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/a")

for (canal in chanels) {
# entrar a un canal 1
  
  channel <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = canal)
  channel$clickElement()
  remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
  
  
  
  # extraer informacion de oferta con rvest
  
  url_actual <- remDr$getCurrentUrl() %>% unlist() %>% xml2::read_html()
  
  data <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoBlockTop']/div[1]/h1") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    tibble(title = .) 
  
  uploads <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock']/div[2]/span[2]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  subs <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock']/div[3]/span[2]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  views <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock']/div[4]/span[2]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  country <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='youtube-user-page-country']") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  type <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='youtube-user-page-channeltype']") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  date <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock']/div[7]/span[2]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  earning <- url_actual %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='socialblade-user-content']/div[3]/div[2]/p[1]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_trim()
  
  data_channel <- data %>% 
    mutate(uploads = uploads, subs = subs, views = views, country = country, type = type, date = date, earning = earning , 
           url = unlist(remDr$getCurrentUrl()))
  


 }
```

Comment: Each time the loop executes it overwrites its previous results. That’s why you get only one channel. Save the results in an array or list, or append the results as a new row in your dataset.

Comment: Why are you not using Youtube API? That is more reliable way to get data.